# Javascript with embedded Ruby: How to safely assign a ruby value to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have this line in a javascript block in a page:

```
res = foo('<%= @ruby_var %>');
```

What is the best way to handle the case where `@ruby_var` has a single-quote in it? Else it will break the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I'd use a ruby [JSON](http://json.org) library on @ruby_var to get proper js syntax for the string and get rid of the '', fex.:

```
res = foo(<%= @ruby_var.to_json %>)
```

(after require "json"'ing, not entirely sure how to do that in the page or if the above syntax is correct as I havn't used that templating language)

(on the other hand, if JSON ever changed to be incompatible with js that'd break, but since a decent amount of code uses eval() to eval json I doubt that'd happen anytime soon)

Comment: Rails already comes with String#to_json, so you don't even need to include any libraries: http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/Object.html#M000022

Comment: .to_json adds html quotes(&quot;) to my string

Answer (score 8):

Rails has method specifically dedicated to this task found in [ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html) called [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript).

In your example, you would use the following:

```
res = foo('<%= escape_javascript @ruby_var %>');
```

Or better yet, use the **j** shortcut:

```
res = foo('<%= j @ruby_var %>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@ruby_var.gsub(/[']/, '\\\\\'')
```

That will escape the single quote with an apostrophe, keeping your Javascript safe!

Also, if you're in Rails, there are a bunch of [Javascript-specific tools](http://rails.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#M000440).

Comment: What if there was a \ already in the code?  You need to escape \ before you escape '.

Comment: yeah, to handle bentilly's case you need: `@ruby_var.gsub(/['\\]/, '\\\\\0')`

Answer (score 2):

Could you just put the string in a double-quote?

```
res = foo("<%= @ruby_var %>");
```

Comment: but then what if @ruby_var has a double quote in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use inspect assuming you know it'll be a single quote:

```
res = foo(<%= @ruby_var.inspect %>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with embedded Ruby too much.  But how about using `p` (which invokes `inspect`) instead of `<%=` which might be doing something like `print` or `puts`.  `p` always prints the string as if it were code wrapped in double quotes:

```
>> p "String ' \" String"
"String ' \" String"
# => nil  
>> p 'alpha " \' alpha'
"alpha \" ' alpha"
# => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the following first property, to get rid of the " from your string and then you can go ahead and use your `json` function.

```
res = foo('<%= @ruby_var %>.first');
```